# Django: CSRF cookie not set. CSRF cookie does not exists

Tags: python, django, cookies, csrf, csrf-token

I have a Django application that serve with uwsgi and nginx. Sometimes when login, There isn't csrf cookie in browser cookie and does not renew when refresh browser.
In login receive

> "CSRF cookie not set."

error and after clean cookie this issue has solved. I used Django runserver for run app and i still have this issue.  my setting is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'app.middlewares.apply_all_requests.SetDefaultLanguage',]

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10 * 60 * 60
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

Comment: Have you got {{ csrf_token }} inside your form?

Comment: Yes, this problem sometimes happens only for some client browser.

Comment: Is it a particular browser? Chrome/Firefox/Edge?

Comment: No, in all browser, i debug csrf middleware and see request cookie is empty, but after delete browser cookie csrf cookie has created and renew in refresh page.